# Magento 2.4.5 product link at admin order gird view

Tags: magento2, order-grid, custom-admin-grid

I want to show the product link on order admin onclick go to storefont product link
or onclick to product thumbnail it open store product ordered image by new tab
exabople link html http://example.com/simple-product-name.html#139=12&138=4
http://example.com/media/catalog/product/a/simple-product-image-link.jpg
thank for your help,
[image: Image demo]

Comment: There may be multiple products ordered in each order. How would you like to show multiple products in the grid?

Comment: Per line product
<a href= "product 1 link">Product 1 name<a>
<a href= "product 2 link">Product 2name<a>

Answer (score 0):

Add your column with a custom renderer: https://meetanshi.com/blog/use-grid-renderer-in-magento-2/

You should get all order items in your renderer and just concatenate them. Keep in mind it's a flat storage so take care to try catch NosuchEntityException in case of the product don't exists.

Comment: Thank you I will try with the guide and show the result after make a change